Button not Completely turning into an Image
My website I'm working on is pixel art, and I'm afraid that could possibly be the problem. In my button I can see my image, but you can also see a huge regular button behind it. I try resizing the image and it just resizes the button behind it too.
HTML:
<button><img src="images/download.png" height="60px" width="60px"></img></button>

I expected it to just show the image as the only part of the button.

Apply the image to the button background, not a child element  background image

You can remove the button styling as described in this answer.

As Lawrence Cherone said, applying to the background gives the -- I guess -- desired result.


<button style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1714334544535-4c5eddeb0ec1');background-size: cover;width: 100px;height: 100px"></button>




It isn't working with my button. I when I was typing "images/download.png", vs code kept saying it was wrong so instead I surrounded it with single quotations. Here is my code now: 

It is <button style="background-image: url('images/download.png');background-size: cover;width: 192px;height: 192px;"></button>.

there is few way to fix it
first one : you can use absolute position and set width , height to 100% , but maybeee it's will be a little bit weird , after that you can resize button to 60px*60px or whatever size you want and after that you make button color, background-color to transparent and set border none and booom, you did it
   button{
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color:transparent;
    border: none;
}

button img{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
    object-fit: cover; /** you can delete this line if you don't like to change image fit */
}

and in second way you can use background-image for you'r button :))

Niether one of these ways are working.

In the first way, I don't think you said how to put the image part in. Thank you for spending your time to help me!
